# Yii2 Class yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth does not exist

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2, google-oauth, yii2-user

I use dektrium/yii2-user (on one project) and yiisoft/yii2-authclient (on another one) to login via Google account.
Some time ago it was everything ok, but i guess after last composer update something was changed and now i get an error: "Class yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth does not exist" when try to open login page.
Does anybody has the same issue or know what's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the config file
Replace from

```
'google'   => [
            'class'        => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
            ..
        ],
```

Replace to

'google'   => [
            'class'        => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
            ...
        ],

Answer (score 6):

`yii2-authclient` has been modified in the latest version which is not backward compatible.
[Read about the upgrade process here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/2.1.0/UPGRADE.md).

Two solutions:

1. Modify composer.json to fetch 2.0.6 version (replace `*` with `2.0.6`) - no other changes are needed but no more updates for this extension.
2. Upgrade your code following the guide in the link above so you can be up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Use yii\authclient\clients\Google instead of yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth in your config file.